# How to bind a Dependency Property to anything in the XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

(Using Silverlight 4.0 and VS 2010)
So I have created a property called `Rank` in my C# file. How do I now tie that to a control in the UserControl xaml file?

My code: (TopicListItem.xaml.cs)

```
    #region Rank (DependencyProperty)

    /// <summary> 
    /// Rank 
    /// </summary> 
    public int Rank
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RankProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RankProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RankProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Rank", typeof(int), typeof(TopicListItem),
        new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnRankChanged)));

    private static void OnRankChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TopicListItem)d).OnRankChanged(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnRankChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    #endregion Rank (DependencyProperty)
```

I want to do this in my TopicListItem.xaml

```
...
<Textblock Text="{TemplateBinding Rank}"/>
...
```

but that doesn't really work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to bind a property in a Usercontrol's xaml to a property exposed by the same UserControl then use the following pattern:-

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Parent.Rank, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
```

Note that this makes the assumption that root content element inside the UserControl has been given the name "LayoutRoot".

Comment: Thanks Anthony...this actually worked while Akash didn't so those reading this please see comments on Akash answer for reasoning why his fails. This UserControl was actually a child and part of a list...thanks again :)

Comment: Anthony, I would love to read more about this and specifically what the logic/reason is behind certain things such as `Parent.` and `ElementName=` ...thanks!

Comment: Actually for this particular control it worked without using the `Parent.` in the path. It found it anyway.

Answer (score 6):

```
<UserControl xmlns..... 
    x:Name="myUserControl">

....

<Textblock Text="{Binding Rank,ElementName=myUserControl}"/>

....

</UserControl>
```

You need to set ElementName to x:Name of UserControl, if x:Name is empty, define one.

Comment: This works fine if the `UserControl` is only ever used as a RootVisual or a navigated page.  However if its used as a child control this approach is likely to fail since the `UserControl` name may be re-assigned by the outer xaml.

Comment: I havent noticed such things, other way would be to specify relative source as self.

Comment: This didn't work since the name needs to be on the root UIElement within the UserControl not on the UserControl itself.

Comment: On further research and experimentation this did actually work. But not if the `Parent.` path syntax is used. So, it seems that `ElementName` sets where the path should start....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Binding, not TemplateBinding,

Also you might want to look into how to get binding errors reported to you - the very helpful default behaviour in WPF is to leave you guessing about binding problems, but you can actually get lots of useful info if you turn it on.

Comment: Thanks will for the tip. HOw can I do this?

Comment: In VS2010 there are options in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window.   Not sure about earlier versions, but you can turn up the wick in code using PresentationTraceSources - that's probably a good term to Google for.

Answer (score -1):

probably `<Textblock Text="{Binding Rank}"/>`.